# Should I upload both the original and the translated documents for Standard Visit Visa to the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas

I will apply for Standard Visit Visa to the UK.
I translated all my Arabic and French documents to English.
Should I upload the English + Arabic or French versions? Or I can upload only the English versions (the translation)?

Comment: If you only upload the translations, how will UKVI know that an original ever existed?

Answer (score 3):

You need to upload both the translated and the original documents to in order to prove the existence of the original document.

Per the [GOV.UK guide to supporting documents](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk):

> If you submit a document that is not in English or Welsh, **it must be
> accompanied by a full translation** that can be independently verified
> by the Home Office. Each translation must contain:
>
> - confirmation from the translator that it is an accurate translation of the original document
> - the date of translation
> - the translator’s full name and signature
> - the translator’s contact details

Comment: So the translation doesn't need to be notarised? Does the translator need to be certified in any way? Could it be a foreign translator? If a document contains just a little bit of text in a foreign language but is otherwise in English (a bit of metadata on a bank printout), does this kind of document need to be translated too (if all the relevant information is already in English)? Many thanks in advance